# Json Jquery Each Loop

Tags: jquery, json

For some reason my Jquery is not looping through my Json data. Current undefined error.

**Json when logged.**

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "storename": "new Store",
            "notes": "test",
            "rejected": "on",
            "offer": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Html**

```
console.log(JsonData);

$.each($.parseJSON(JsonData), function(idx, obj) {
        alert(obj.storename);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to parse your jSON here anymore, so you can use:

```
$.each(JsonData.cities, function(idx, obj) {
     alert(obj.storename);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs6rZ/)**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a object for me, also you need to iterate through the cities property

```
console.log(JsonData);

$.each(JsonData.cities, function (idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.storename);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looping through the wrong object, my bad.

```
 $.each($.parseJSON(JsonData), function(idx, cities) {
                          $.each(cities, function(idx, obj){
                           console.log(obj.storename)
                          });
    });
```